# Display Oracle Raw Data Image in JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

My following code work fine.

```
                byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes("PHOTO_PIC");
                response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
                response.getOutputStream().write(bytes, 1, bytes.length);
```

but when I save picture from oracle form 6i it not display on jsp page. If i save picture through jsp it work fine.

I've tried to save image in folder through form 6i it also wont show up in jsp. Once I open in ms paint and save as copy then it display on jsp.

My Oracle datatype is Long Raw

Comment: Perhaps you should also show the code that saves the picture - it looks the problem is probably there.

Comment: I've no access to that desktop application that save pictures

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. the problem is with oracle side. It save file in tiff format. I used converter then working ok.